# Accidentally mixed ginger in with ginger beer plant grains--how can I fix this?

Tags: ginger-beer, grain, mistakes

Fortunately the ginger is pretty finely ground. Should I just leave it in there indefinitely as I cycle through new batches and hope it disintegrates? It doesn't seem like filtering will work very well without losing the majority of the ginger beer plant grains.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? And what are you trying to achieve? Is is taste that bothers you? Look? Or just the fact itself?

Answer (score 1):

You will be fine, it will either get consumed or diluted as you grow and divide your plant.